# Garbage Disposal Tailpiece - Do they make other sizes or solution to overcome size which is not quite right

Tags: plumbing, pvc, garbage-disposal

I went to disconnect my old garbage disposal and I twisted a new one in place. The problem is when the tailpiece is attached to the new garbage disposal, the kitchen pipes are about 3/4" away from the tailpiece so the tailpiece does not quite extend enough away from the disposal.

I have a generic tailpiece included here to show you what I mean.  The diameter is fine on my tailpiece.  The length is fine and I can make that work.  What I am saying is that the small piece before the bend, if that were to be 3/4" longer then my pipes would connect correctly.  Is there such a piece, or what can I do to correct for this extra gap?

[image]

Is it something like [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/InSinkErator-Flexible-Discharge-Tube-2-in-White-Plastic-Garbage-Disposal-Discharge-Tube/1269327?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-kab-_-ggl-_-LIA_KAB_188_Kitchen-Sinks-Disposers-_-1269327-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=Cj0KCQiAxoiQBhCRARIsAPsvo-x1zl-K0yR_iBaXbsXKZB9YGkFQGbv4jaaej2hNuBEdVFFBSqnDsmAaAo3AEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: I'm sure different brands have slightly different dimensions, but generally it's just a matter of stacking together the right combination of parts. A clear photo would _really_ help get you confident answers.

Comment: Don't use flexible parts if you can help it. They're more prone to clog. Are you sure there isn't some slip adjustment available in the _other_ parts that would allow proper alignment?

Comment: @isherwood Yeah I just talked with a plumber I know.  He suggested that perhaps there is another nut that would allow the necessary rotation to place because the gap is so small.  I am going to see if the produces the necessary adjustment.

Comment: If you include a picture of your actual installation instead of "random image from the internet", you'll get much more accurate and appropriate help instead of best guesses.